# Callbacks in aasm gem and ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, actionmailer, aasm

Im learning ruby on rails and have a trouble with aasm callbacks and actionmailer.
I have a hotels model. Heres a code:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM

  scope :approved_hotels, -> { where(aasm_state: "approved") }

  has_many :comments
    belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
    has_many :ratings
  belongs_to :address

  aasm do
    state :pending, initial: true
    state :approved
    state :rejected

    event :approve, :after => :send_email do
      transitions from: :pending, to: :approved 
    end
    event :reject, :after => :send_email do
      transitions from: :pending, to: :rejected
    end
  end

  def send_email

  end
end
```

As you see user has to get email when state of the hotel he added was changed. Heres what i wrote but its not THE solution cos user gets emails every time admin updates hotel with "pending" state.

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :top5hotels]

  def update
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])

    if @hotel.aasm_state == "pending"
      @hotel.aasm_state = params[:state]
      UserMailer.changed_state_email(current_user, @hotel.name, 
      @hotel.aasm_state).deliver
    end

    if @hotel.update_attributes!(params[:hotel])
      redirect_to admin_hotel_path(@hotel), notice: "Hotel was successfully updated."
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

So i think i need to use callback but i dont know how to call

```
UserMailer.changed_state_email(current_user, @hotel.name, 
        @hotel.aasm_state).deliver
```

from the model. 
I tried

```
UserMailer.changed_state_email(User.find(:id), Hotel.find(:name), 
        Hotel.find(aasm_state)).deliver
```

but that doesnt work. 
 Im really out of options and looking for any help.
Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**
Thank to Amit Sharma! I`ve made these changes and now getting

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

Looks like user object Im passing to changed_state_email() method is nill but I have no idea why.
Here is my mailer file aswell:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "localhost"

  # Send email to user when hotels state change
  def changed_state_email(user, hotel_name, current_state)
    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'State of your hotel  '+hotel_name+'has been 
        changed to  '+current_state)
  end
end
```

Here is a result of puts "====#{self.inspect}":

```
====#<Hotel id: nil, name: "CoolName", breakfast: nil, room_description: nil, price_for_room: 34, star_rating: 3, user_id: nil, address_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, average_rating: nil, photo_file_name: nil, photo_content_type: nil, photo_file_size: nil, photo_updated_at: nil, aasm_state: "approved">
```

F.====#
F.====#

**UPDATE 2:**
It returns user object. Output from the console:

```
1.9.3-p551 :006 > h = Hotel.find(1)
  Hotel Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "hotels".* FROM "hotels" WHERE "hotels"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Hotel id: 1, name: "QWERTYUI", breakfast: nil, room_description: nil, price_for_room: 44, star_rating: 4, user_id: 2, address_id: nil, created_at: "2015-05-30 22:55:01", updated_at: "2015-05-30 22:55:01", average_rating: nil, photo_file_name: nil, photo_content_type: nil, photo_file_size: nil, photo_updated_at: nil, aasm_state: "pending"> 
1.9.3-p551 :007 > h
 => #<Hotel id: 1, name: "QWERTYUI", breakfast: nil, room_description: nil, price_for_room: 44, star_rating: 4, user_id: 2, address_id: nil, created_at: "2015-05-30 22:55:01", updated_at: "2015-05-30 22:55:01", average_rating: nil, photo_file_name: nil, photo_content_type: nil, photo_file_size: nil, photo_updated_at: nil, aasm_state: "pending"> 
1.9.3-p551 :008 > h.user
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 => #<User id: 2, name: "qwerty", email: "qweqweqweqwe@qwe.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$FG5xXb/9wYLcdsCrfJtuDOTsslyY8p.m0qkbP4a5OEvJ...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, admin: false, created_at: "2015-05-30 22:54:14", updated_at: "2015-05-30 22:54:14", comments_count: 0, hotels_count: 1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this. I hope this will help you.

In **Hotels Controller**.

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :top5hotels]

  def update
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])

    if @hotel.pending?
      if params[:state] == "approved"
        @hotel.approved!
      elsif params[:state] == "rejected"
        @hotel.rejected!
      end
   end

    if @hotel.update_attributes!(params[:hotel])
      redirect_to admin_hotel_path(@hotel), notice: "Hotel was successfully updated."
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

In **Hotel** model.

```
def send_email
  user = self.user
  puts "====#{self.inspect}===#{user.inspect}"
  UserMailer.changed_state_email(user, self.name, 
  self.aasm_state).deliver
end
```

Please revert back to me if you face any issue.

Comment: Thank you for respond! Well, now Im getting "undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass"
looks like self.user object is nill, but i have no idea why

Comment: in User model do you have this `has_many :hotels` or `has_one :hotel` ?

Comment: I have edited my answer and added fix in `send_email` method, please check and try to run the code.

Comment: also please add this `puts "====#{self.inspect}"` line in `send_email` method on the top and so your `hotel` object get printed on log. Take that result and paste it here.

Comment: Still same error `undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass`. I updated post as you requested

Comment: Edited the answer please try to run it and post the result of `puts "====#{hotel.inspect}===#{user.inspect}"`

Comment: `undefined local variable or method `hotel' for #<Hotel:0x000000062b9c78>` Here is a link to my [github](https://github.com/Prog1Dev/HotelAdvisorApp) if it helps

Comment: updated my answer added changes in controller action, please check

Comment: I updated my code like you said. Still same error `NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: in rails console find the hotel with the id which you are using for update. e.g. `h = Hotel.find(1)` then type `h.user` and see whearher it returns `user` object or not.

Comment: updated the answer check wheather it get printed on log or not.